# can't read directory using listdir command in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

let us suppose  i have  a lot of images located in this directory

```
directory ='/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/GAN network/Celebra/img_align_celeba'
```

i have done following steps in order  to  read and show all images :
step 1 : mount  drive

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

step 2: create a directory  variable

```
directory ='/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/GAN network/Celebra/img_align_celeba'
```

step 3:create a basic code  for reading files

```
from os import listdir
from numpy import asarray
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def load_image(filename):
  image =Image.open(filename)
  image =image.convert('RGB')
  pixels =asarray(image)
  return pixels
def load_faces(directory,n_faces):
  faces =list()
  for filename in listdir(directory):
    pixesl =load_image(directory + filename)
    faces.append(pixels)
    if len(faces) >= n_faces:
      break
  return asarray(faces)
def plot_faces(faces,n):
  for i in range(n*n):
    plt.subplot(n,n,1+i)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.imshow(faces[i])
  plt.show()
```

and final step is to check program :

```
faces =load_faces(directory,25)
print('Loaded: ', faces.shape)
plot_faces(faces,5)
```

but it gives me following error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-3392f98fc252> in <module>()
----> 1 faces =load_faces(directory,25)
      2 print('Loaded: ', faces.shape)
      3 plot_faces(faces,5)

<ipython-input-8-99365c573bbf> in load_faces(directory, n_faces)
     10 def load_faces(directory,n_faces):
     11   faces =list()
---> 12   for filename in listdir(directory):
     13     pixesl =load_image(directory + filename)
     14     faces.append(pixels)

OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error: '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/GAN network/Celebra/img_align_celeba'
```

please help me to clarify what is wrong?

Comment: Most of your code is unrelated to the problem. You could just have a few line example that does the `listdir`. To debug, you could do listdir in the parent directories, e.g. `listdir('/content/drive/My Drive')` then `listdir('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks')` etc... to see if the structure is what you think it is.

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with `listdir` too. My solutions were to force the drive mount and to use `glob` to list files in the folder.

```py
import glob
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/gdrive', force_remount=True)
files = glob.glob(f"/gdrive/My Drive/path_to_folder")    
for file in files:
    do_something(file)
```

Comment: thank you my friend, i have already solved it, thanks for your advice, yes i have used  glob in one of task